# System.Threading.Timer and CA1823:AvoidUnusedPrivateFields

Tags: c#, code-analysis

I'm getting this code analysis error: CA1823:AvoidUnusedPrivateFields, for this line of code:

```
private static Timer _timer;
```

In the constructor of my class, I have this:

```
_timer = new Timer(OnTimerElapsed, _autoResetEvent, 1000, 1000);
```

I don't need to call any methods on the timer; simply instantiating it is enough. Is that why I'm getting the CA warning? Is this a case where I really just need to suppress the error, or am I missing something?

As a side note, I'm not getting an error that I should be calling Dispose() on the timer. Shouldn't I be getting that error?

**-- Edit --**

If I make the _timer an instance field, then I get the error about not calling Dispose() on it. Why would static vs. instance matter for that?

Comment: As for your side question: Which rule set do you have selected for Code Analysis?

Comment: We have our own ruleset, but CA1001 (types that own disposable fields should be disposable) is enabled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting the warning because you are not accessing the `_timer` variable after assigning to it.

The reason that the errors are different depending on whether or not the variable is static is exactly because of the nature of static variables.  A static variable is an part of the *type*, not of any particular object.  Its lifetime is tied to the lifetime of an application domain, and not of any particular object.  Since its lifetime is tied to that of the application domain, the owner of the application domain is responsible for the timer's cleanup.  The owner of the application domain is the CLR itself, so the CLR will clean up your static timer.  Static analysis does not complain that you do not call `Dispose` because the timer's finalizer will be called while the app domain is unloaded.

If the timer were an instance field, its lifetime would be tied to that of the object which owns it.  In that case, the timer's cleanup would be the responsibility of the owning object.  In C#, such object-member cleanup is performed using the Disposal pattern.  If you haven't implemented that pattern (by implementing `IDisposable`) VS static analysis will issue a warning.

Now that being said, timers are a special case of `IDisposable`.  They are special because even if you are "using" the timer (by executing code in its callback), you are not accessing the timer object itself.  Hence, you might be tempted to think of the `Timer` class as a *service*.  That is, you might think that the `Timer` constructor is more like a `RegisterForPeriodicCallbacks` method.  That is wrong.  `Timer` is an object, and in C# you have to treat it as such.  You must think of `Timer` as an object with lifetime, and one that is determined by some other object.

If you want the lifetime of the timer to be tied to the lifetime of the application, then you should make a static variable of type `System.Timers.Timer` rather than `System.Threading.Timer`.  When you want the timer to begin ticking, simply call its `Start` method.

If you want the lifetime of the timer to be tied to the lifetime of some other object, then you should store it as a field in that other container object, and be sure to correctly implement the Disposal pattern on the container object.

If you do either of these things, all of the static analysis warnings will go away.

Comment: `If you want the lifetime of the timer to be tied to the lifetime of the application, then you should make a static variable of type System.Timers.Timer rather than System.Threading.Timer.` Why is that?

Comment: I am assuming that if you are worried about static analysis your application is more than a few lines of code.  If your application is large, and you want a timer tied to the application's lifetime,  then chances are good you will have more than one object subscribing to the timer.  The `Timers` timer has an `Elapsed` event that supports multiple subscribers.  Also, subscribers themselves can be responsible for adding and removing themselves from the timers `Elapsed` event, rather than putting that burden on the creator of the `Timer` (probably your entry point).

Answer (score 4):

Just initializing the field is not considered using it. You need to actually USE it :)

In regards to your "Edit" you should never dispose a static object, otherwise there will be problems trying to access it in the future. That is why the warnings worked as you stated.

Comment: In this case, instantiating it is all that's necessary, so I really am using it the way it was meant to be used. So you're saying that this is a correct time to just suppress the error, right?

Comment: Better yet, get rid of the field. There's no reason to store the field if you're not using it.

Comment: This really doesn't actually address *solving* the issue.  He could USE it; but if he doesn't need do; that's worse than the warning itself.

Comment: @PeterRitchie - He asked why he was getting the warning, my answer certainly does address the question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using System.Windows.Forms.Timer, I think there's another issue that this warning raises.  It's safe to either ignore this warning or remove your `_timer` variable.  But, the timer will continue to run while your application is exiting.  You probably don't want that.  I'd suggest using this variable by disabling the timer and potentially disposing it upon exit.

Comment: The timer runs on a background thread so it will not continue firing when the application exits. If you remove the variable it will be garbage collected and cease firing.

Comment: Depends on which type of Timer it is. http://bit.ly/MImkc9 details "The timer is not subject to garbage collection when the value is true." describing the Enabled property.

Comment: He is using `System.Threading.Timer`.  None of the other timers have a constructor with that prototype.